# How do AWS Lambda instances scale?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I understand that AWS Lambda is supposed to abstract the developer from the infrastructure. However I don't quite understand how scaling would work.

Does it automatically start new containers during high traffic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AWS Lambda functions can be triggered by many different [event sources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html).

AWS Lambda runs each Lambda function runs as a standalone process in its own environment. There is a default limit of 1000 concurrent Lambda functions.

There is no need to think of Lambda "scaling". Rather, whenever an event source (or your own application) runs a Lambda function, the environment is created, the function is run, and the environment is torn down. When there is nothing that is invoking a Lambda function, it is not running. When 1000 invocations happen, then 1000 Lambda functions run.

It "scales" automatically by running in parallel on AWS infrastructure. You only pay while a function is running, per 100ms. It is the job of AWS to ensure that their back-end infrastructure scales to support the number of Lambda functions being run by all customers in aggregate.

Comment: Right, I'm just a little concern based on what I read in the aws docs. It seems to reuse containers and the implementation of that logic seems to be a blackbox.

Comment: It's easy to handle. Your Lambda function should not assume that it was the "first" to run in the environment. It should clean-up after itself (eg delete temp files). The benefit of re-using environments is that they remove the start-up time, so the functions execute quicker (especially for Java functions). If no containers are available for re-use, new ones will be deployed, so it will not impact the ability to scale.

Comment: Regarding "There is a default limit of 100 concurrent Lambda functions.". 
I've found in AWS docs: "The default concurrency limit across all functions per region in a given account is 1,000".

Comment: Thanks @Andriy -- now updated. (It has changed over time.)

Answer (score -1):

If you whant to change the nubmer of desired instanzes in Auto Scaling Group, you chan use `botocore.session`

```python
import botocore.session

client = session.create_client('autoscaling')

   client.set_desired_capacity(
        AutoScalingGroupName='NAME',
        DesiredCapacity=X,
        HonorCooldown=True|False
    )
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/set-desired-capacity.html